# TypeError: HybridTableMaskedLM.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

Here I am asking about this recurrent, sometimes obvious, issue. I'm execution this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WTg-YnfNVX4M0P0m1mEJYDQVkWr4HKXl). However, I get the error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-24-7a312b60bb5c> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 config = PretrainedConfig.from_pretrained("./config.json")
      2 print(config)
----> 3 model = HybridTableMaskedLM(config)
      4 tinybert_model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("huawei-noah/TinyBERT_General_4L_312D")
      5 model.load_pretrained(tinybert_model.state_dict())

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    447 
    448         if self.call_super_init is False and bool(args):
--> 449             raise TypeError("{}.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but {} were"
    450                             " given".format(type(self).__name__, len(args) + 1))
    451 

TypeError: HybridTableMaskedLM.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

when execution the line :

```
model = HybridTableMaskedLM(PretrainedConfig.from_pretrained("./config.json"))
```

The definition of HybridTableMaskedLM in the previous block is :

```
class HybridTableMaskedLM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(HybridTableMaskedLM, self).__init__(config)

        self.table = HybridTableModel(config)
        self.cls = TableMLMHead(config)

        self.init_weights()
```

and the one in model.py is

```
class HybridTableMaskedLM(BertPreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super(HybridTableMaskedLM, self).__init__(config)

        self.table = HybridTableModel(config)
        self.cls = TableMLMHead(config)

        self.init_weights()
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to make a [mre] including minimal but complete code to reproduce the issue, including imports, plus add the tags for all relevant libraries. Normally there should be no reason to have two definitions of the same class, but I'm not familiar with the library(s) you're using so I don't know if there's a purpose to that.

Comment: And the traceback doesn't match the line you're pointing out.

Comment: I missed that this is from a notebook. I suppose the two definitions are for demonstration then. But my point is, only one of them can be used at a time.